# Flask returning 404 for anything

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

This is my app.py

```py
import logging.config

import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, url_for
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_restplus import Api

from authentek import settings
from authentek.api.blog.endpoints.posts import ns as blog_posts_namespace
from authentek.api.blog.endpoints.categories import ns as blog_categories_namespace
from authentek.api.auth.endpoints.users import ns as users_namespace
from authentek.api.restplus import api
from authentek.database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
logging_conf_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../logging.conf'))
logging.config.fileConfig(logging_conf_path)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


@app.route("/sitemap")
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        # Filter out rules we can't navigate to in a browser
        # and rules that require parameters
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    # links is now a list of url, endpoint tuples

def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
    flask_app.config['SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = settings.RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = settings.RESTPLUS_VALIDATE
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = settings.RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER
    flask_app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = settings.RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP


def initialize_app(flask_app):
    configure_app(flask_app)

    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
    # api.init_app(blueprint)
    migrate = Migrate(flask_app, db)
    api.add_namespace(blog_posts_namespace)
    api.add_namespace(blog_categories_namespace)
    api.add_namespace(users_namespace)

    if blueprint.name not in flask_app.blueprints.keys():
        flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    else:
        flask_app.blueprints[blueprint.name] = blueprint
    print(flask_app.blueprints)
    db.init_app(flask_app)


    api.init_app(flask_app)


def main():
    from authentek.database.models import Post, Category, User, BlacklistToken  # noqa
    app.config.from_object(settings)
    initialize_app(app)
    log.info('>>>>> Starting development server at http://{}/api/ <<<<<'.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

forget about all the routes, at least /sitemap should work!

Comment: /sitemap does not have a return. You have code that is executed outside of the main function. Your code is not really reproducible. In the end, sitemap returns me 500 for not returning anything, so no 404 as you mentioned.

Comment: I found out that it does not respect the url prefix

Comment: can you post as an answer ?